# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' when updating an image to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

I'm having trouble updating images into my database in MySQL.

I'm using a combobox to select a user ID and populate that combobox with that ID and the image that's associated with that ID on a picturebox

I can add and remove images just fine, but the problem is when I try to update any image i get the error " Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' ".

I've looked it up and it has something to do with passing an array of bytes to a single byte, which is not possible.

Here's my code to update the image:

```
Dim filesize As UInteger

Dim imgcliente As New MemoryStream
PictureBox1.Image.Save(imgcliente, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)

Dim arrImage As Byte() = imgcliente.GetBuffer
filesize = imgcliente.Length
imgcliente.Close()
```

And here's my code to retrive the associated image from the ID:

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT Imagem_Cliente FROM adegages.clientes WHERE ID_Cliente='" & cmb_cliente.Text & "'", con)

Dim imagedata As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

If Not imagedata Is Nothing Then
    Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length)
        ms.Write(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length)
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms, True))
    End Using
End If
```

It's probably just some line and it may be incredibly ease to solve, but I just can't seem to figure out where I'm wrong.

Thx in advance

Edit:

This is the code to edit records to the database

```
Dim atualizar_vendas As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE vendas SET ID_Venda=@ID, 
  Cliente_Venda=@CLIENTE, Data_Venda=@DATA, Qnt_Vinho_Venda=@QNT, 
  Tipo_Casta_Venda=@TIPO_CASTA, Nome_Casta_Venda=@NOME_CASTA, 
  Total_Venda=@TOTAL, Imagem_Cliente=@IMG WHERE ID_Venda = @ID", con)

        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = txt_id_venda.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@CLIENTE", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmb_cliente.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@DATA", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mtx_data_venda.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@QNT", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_qnt_vendida.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@TIPO_CASTA", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmb_tipo_casta.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@NOME_CASTA", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmb_nome_casta.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@TOTAL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_total.Text
        atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@IMG", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = arrImage

        Try
            con.Open()
            If atualizar_vendas.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Editado com sucesso!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "AdegaGes")
                Limpar()
            End If

            con.Close()

            Retrieve_Clientes()
            Retrieve_Tipo_Casta()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "AdegaGes")
            con.Close()
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Comment: Yikes. This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also, the code to update the image doesn't show how it writes to the database. We need to see that part.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I've edited the post and have placed the code of how I'm updating to the database

Comment: You are wrong in this  `atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@IMG", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = arrImage`. You cannot put a parameter as array object for a `MySqlDbType.Int32` Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
atualizar_vendas.Parameters.Add("@IMG", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = arrImage
```

That parameter is asking for a single integer, instead of a byte array. You probably want `MySqlDbType.Blob` there instead.

Comment: Well anyways thanks and I will be paying more attention from now on

Comment: I was doing some conversions using BitConverter.Int32 maybe that's why that was there in the first place